# Bad translation QueryDSL update query into native sql

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, querydsl

I am using QueryDSL with spring's JPA, and I have problem with final query which is created from my JPAUpdateClause.

here is my what my QueryDSL's query looks like:

```
    final JPAUpdateClause updateQuery = new JPAUpdateClause(this.em, qPerson)
            .set(qPerson.hixNumber, 10000)
            .set(qPerson.fixNumber, 20000)
            .where(qPerson.role.type.eq(RoleType.ADMIN));
```

When I execute it I got following exception:

```
I Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement ...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "cross"
```

So I start debugging and I found generated JPQL which still looks fine:

```
update Person person
set person.hixNumber= ?1
set person.fixNumber= ?2
where person.role.type = ?3
```

and when I enable logging of SQL queries I find out there is wrong generated native query:

```
update person cross join  set hix_humber=?, set fix_humber=? where type=?
```

Can you tell me how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Any luck solving this problem? I'm having the same issue.